# LDRB in ARM Keil - What Exactly is Happening

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I've recently started on learning an assembly language. I've been looking at a piece of code that I'm not entirely sure what it does.

```
    LDR r0, =str
    MOV r1, #0
loop 
    LDRB r2, [r0], #1
    ADD r1, r1, #1
    CMP r2, #0
    BNE loop
    SUB r1, r1, #1
Data Segment Little Endian Format
    str DCB "mCQ5Gtq",0
```

From my understanding, DCB loads the string into a word of 32 bits, and each character has its own byte. Little Endian Format means the least significant byte is stored in the lower memory address.
LDR makes r0 = the string.
LDRB loads the least significant byte held in r0, into r2 offset by 1 bit.

1) Does the least significant byte start with m or q? i.e. would it be
 <- 0000 0017 (ascii for q) or <- 0000 006D (ascii for m).

2) Does the LDRB operator load the least significant byte from r0 offset by 1 bit, into r2. If so, what would r2 be (just the first loop).

Thank you very much

Comment: 1) with `m`. Strings in memory are not affected by endianness. 2) that's 1 byte not 1 bit and that's a post increment anyway. So it loads the first character and increments `r0` to point to the next one. Learn to use a debugger so you can single step code for yourself.

Comment: This is presumably homework. The first load uses a label, it  is the address of the string. Everything else should be a case of reading your notes.

Comment: _"DCB loads the string into a word of 32 bits"_ `DCB` just statically places a sequence of bytes (in this case `"mCQ5Gtq",0`) at the current location (in this case the start of the data segment). You've also given this location the symbolic name `str` to make it easier for other parts of the program to refer to that location.

Comment: To be precise,the string is stored in two words or 8 bytes of memory.